# WCF Web service getting aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, wcf

I have following Webservice returning JSON :

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public SomeResultClass AddObject(InputObject objInputObject)
    {
        IO objIO = new IO();
        return objIO.AddObject(objInputObject);
    }
```

on client side I am calling the webservice as following:

```
   var Data=new Object();
   Data.objInputObject=new Object();
   //Add fields
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(Data),
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            url: "../Webservice/WSService.svc/AddObject",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
               show_Result(result.AddObjectResult);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
               show_Error(msg);
            }
        });
```

But the ajax call always gets aborted....also if I add breakpoint in webservice ..it is hit twice....??....the webservice code seem to be executed properly.. but status in browser is aborted?

Comment: Have you set breakpoint in you ajax method .

Comment: Also check your executionTimeout (in httpRuntime element) in service web config.

Comment: yes....it is hit only once :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution.....It Seems WCF Doesn't allow `DateTime` null values...
I have `public DateTime SortDateTime { get; set; }` which was not assigned any value..

Just changed model class constructor to initialize it :

```
public class InputObject 
{
    public InputObject ()
    {
        SortDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    //Fields
    public DateTime SortDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was returning a large amount of record from the server, i added the following line to my wcf config file and it worked.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="262144" executionTimeout="103600"/>
</system.web>
```

Hope it also work for you.Please try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem or error is in Javascript Object Notation when serialize; not in WCF.

["•The JavaScript date is  based on a time value that is milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

DateTime with value Year=1, Month=1, and Day = 1..31 throw exception. where Year = 1..yyyy, Month = 2..MM, Day=1..DD and so on works fine. ("MyDateTime":"/Date(-62132950800000+0000)/")

I did a massive test with 'DateTime', but the problem is within the limits.

As DateTime is a ValueType then null values do not is allowed, but `Nullable<DateTime>` also works fine.("MyDateTime":null)

I had the same problem today. (thanks Shashank Kumar)